# C# TreeView duplicate nodes and child

Tags: c#, treeview, devexpress, nodes

I have created a treeview but i have a problem.

In my code nodes was added duplicately like this;

[image: treeview]

[image: treeview]

How can i solve and code this issue?

My data is;

```
Column1     Column2
category      subcategory
category      subcategory2
category      subcategory3 
test          subtest
test          subtest2
```

My code;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from mytable", con);
da.Fill(dt);

treeView1.Nodes.Add("Documents");

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{            
     TreeNode nod = new TreeNode(dr["kategori"].ToString());
     nod.Nodes.Add(dr["altkategori"].ToString());
     treeView1.Nodes.Add(nod);
}
```

Comment: And what are your expectations? How should it look like?

Comment: I presume that all `subcategory(1/2)` should appear in the same `category` node.

Comment: You need to group your data by Column1. You could use dictionary where Key is value from Column1 and Value is a list of values from Column2 for a Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that you create another `category` and `test` node respectively for each `subcategory` and `subtest`.

Using [LINQ GroupBy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) will group your `altkategori` inside the same `kategori` node:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Documents");

foreach (IGrouping<string, string> kategori in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(dr => dr["kategori"].ToString(), dr => dr["altkategori"].ToString()))
{
    TreeNode nod = new TreeNode(kategori.Key); // node with kategori text

    foreach (string altkategori in kategori)   // foreach subnode in kategori
        nod.Nodes.Add(altkategori);            // add another altkategori node in

    treeView1.Nodes.Add(nod);                  // add your final kategori node
}
```

Tell me if you are not confident about LINQ, and/or if you need more explanation.

Comment: your code is working thank you bro. You are the man. I had struggling for two days. @Maxime Recuerda do you want something from Turkey?

Comment: ahah no thank you, but don't forget to mark the answer as validated (on the left)

Answer (score 0):

TreeViews are not working like a Dictionary

If you want such behavior, you need to properly build the tree yourself.

If it stays at two layers, things are fairly easy: just use a `new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();` and add your subcategories.

Later, you can iterate over the items in the dictionary, and create the subnodes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for an existing node with the same text and reuse it, and only create a new node when necessary.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{            
    TreeNode nod = treeView1.Nodes.Find(dr["kategori"].ToString());
    if (nod == null) 
    { 
        nod = new TreeNode(dr["kategori"].ToString());
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(nod);
    }
    nod.Nodes.Add(dr["altkategori"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, 'Nodes.Items[]' was wrong - I've edited my sample to 'Nodes.Find()' instead. That row should return an existing node the second time a category appears.